# Import XML data source in Google docs using API

Tags: java, xml, google-docs-api

I have XML data source. I want to import this XML data source in  Google docs(Spreadsheet) using API in java.Is this thing possible?Or Is there any another way to store xml data as csv file in JAVA?

Answer (score 0):

try this library http://www.ricebridge.com/xml-csv-convert.htm

I haven't used it before, but from the description it should do what you want (xml to csv)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not restricted to use Java, you could use the IMPORTXML function Google docs offers:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_landing", "//a/@href")
```

Source:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en